# setting Java Environment Variable in JIB Image from Helm

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I need to set a Java Environment Variable: -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=classpath:store. I am using helm charts with azure devops to release the image onto Openshift. In the deployment.yaml, I have tried multiple options to try to set the env variable but in vain. One example is as per below:

```
 spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          env:
            - name: JAVA_OPTIONS
              value: "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=classpath:store"
```

Thanks to guide.

Ashley

Answer (score 0):

It can works but it requires that the containers are aware of the environment variables. So you may need to declare the variable in the `Dockerfile` and you must use the environment variable in the `CMD` instruction that is used to start the process in the container.
The environment variable will be updated with the value you provided in the kubernetes manifest.

See below, a very simple Dockerfile to demonstrate the usage:

```
FROM openjdk:11
ENV JAVA_OPTIONS=""

COPY myapp.jar myapp.jar

CMD java ${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dmy.other.java.property=value -jar myapp.jar
```